How do I solve $\int \frac{e^{\sqrt{x}}\sqrt{e^{\sqrt{x}}-1}}{\sqrt{x}}dx$?
For context I'm learning indefinite integrals and it's my first year at university I had no prior experience with Integrals. So it's my first time solving problems like this one.
I need to solve this indefinite integral by u-substitution, but I can't really get any decent answer, I've tried to substitute $u$ in $\sqrt{e^{\sqrt{x}}-1}$.
I got this as solution.$$\frac{e^{\sqrt{x+1}}\left ( e^{\sqrt{x}}-1 \right )^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3\sqrt{x}}+C$$
But none of the basic math software I use could confirm my solution. Photomath could not solve this, and Symbolab gave me a really different solution.
This is the solution I got from Symbolab.$$\frac{4}{3}\left ( e^{\sqrt{x}}-1 \right )^{\frac{3}{2}}+C$$
It applied u-substitution but since I don't own Symbolab Pro it only shows me that aplied u-substitution as following. 
$$\int 2\sqrt{u}\; du$$ 
It doesn't tell me how it got it so I tried substituting $\sqrt{x}$ since it's the power of e and also the denominator of the entire fraction, I hit a wall pretty soon differentiating dt. I was using t as my substitute variable, here is that attempt. 
$$t = \sqrt{x}$$
$$dt = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} dx$$
Here is the point where I've got stuck since I don't know how to proceed. Am I supposed to move the 2 to multiply dt? And leave the $\sqrt{x}$ behind? To have the following: 
$$2dt = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx$$
Changing signs it should match the integral such as: $$-2dt = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx$$But Is this possible?. I'll be very happy if you guys can point my mistakes and guide me in the right direction. Also some recommendations of software to check my solutions would help. Thanks for reading.

Regarding softwares to check your integrals, you can try this and this

$$I=\int \frac{e^{\sqrt{x}}\sqrt{e^{\sqrt{x}}-1}}{\sqrt{x}}dx$$
$\sqrt{x}=t\implies \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx=2dt$
$$I=2\int {e^{t}\sqrt{e^{t}-1}}\,dt$$
$e^t-1=z\implies e^t\,dt=dz$
$$I=2\int {\sqrt{z}}\,dz=\frac{4}{3}z^{\frac{3}{2}}+C$$
Using $\int \sqrt{x}\,dx=\frac{2}{3}x^{\frac{3}{2}}+C$
$$I=\frac{4}{3}z^{\frac{3}{2}}+C\implies\frac{4}{3}(e^t-1)^{\frac{3}{2}}+C\implies \frac{4}{3}(e^{\sqrt{x}}-1)^{\frac{3}{2}}+C$$
Am I supposed to move the 2 to multiply dt?
Yes, refer above
But Is this possible?
Yes

Let $e^{\sqrt x}-1=u$, so $\dfrac{e^{\sqrt x}}{2\sqrt x}\,\mathrm dx=\mathrm du$, you integral becomes:
$$I=2\int \sqrt{e^{\sqrt x}-1} \,\frac{e^{\sqrt x}}{2\sqrt x}\,\mathrm dx=2\int\sqrt u\, \mathrm du $$
I assume you're able to solve the last integral, don't forget to go back to the $x$ variable.

Start off with $e^{\sqrt{x}}=u$
so $\frac{e^{\sqrt{x}}dx}{\sqrt{x}}=2du$
so you essentially have to $$2\int\sqrt{u-1}du$$
which is equivalent to $$\frac{4}{3}(e^{\sqrt{x}}-1)^{\frac{3}{2}}+C$$
